# Is my thinking about mvvm right?

Tags: mvvm

I'm having a little bit of a hard time getting into mvvm. I'm writing a simple app, Notebook. I have one viewmodel, it's name is actually `ViewModel`. It has an `ObservableCollection` of Notes inside and methods to save and load those from Isolated Storage. My only Model is Note.cs, it implements INotifyPropertyChanged and I'm of course `RaisingPropertyChanged`.

I've also got two view, both of them are user controls. One to display list of notes and one to edit the one chosen from the list.

My questions are:

- Where do I create an instance of my vievmodel?
- How should I implement going from the page with list of notes to the page with detailed view after choosing one Note to edit? At the
  moment I'm saving the index of Note in App.xaml.cs, going to the next page and setting
  the DetailedView `DataContext` to the right Note in `OnNavigatedTo`, but
  I don't think it's actually the perfect solution.
- Where should I save my Notes? I guess `Application_Closing` in App.xaml.cs is the right place to do it, but I'd have to have my viewmodel as a global object there, is this the right approach?

Additional question:
I have to add possibility to group notes. I guess that class Group with dictionary `(GroupName, howManyNotes)` is going to be allright since I don't have to be able to for example write all notes from selected group. Do you think there's a better approach I should think about?

Thanks for respones,
Michał.

Comment: Have you heard about `MVVMLight` Framework?

Comment: I have heard about this and other frameworks too, but I wanted to start without them. I think I'll give it a go then, thanks.

Comment: Well, since you are very new to MVVM, those framework might actually help you understand how it works. They are designed to help beginners use the MVVM pattern. I'm sure that after you will experience with them, you will understand exactly how broad is your question, and you will also be able to answer it by yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Also check out Catel, it's very active and has lots of good documentation: http://www.catelproject.com

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at `Calibrun.Micro` which is a great framework for MVVM. You can get some sample from the CodePlex.

I have used that in a bunch of Project, and will give you flexibility in case if your project grows in size.

Google for Caliburn.Micro sample and you will find a number of sample for all technologies like WPF, Silverlight, Windows Store, Windows Mobile.

[Caliburn.Micro CodePlex](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/)